# iOS - UITableView Detect When Finger Crosses Keyboard While Scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, touch, detect

I have a feature in my app very similiar to the native Messages app. I like how the keyboard gets hidden when the messages table is scrolled and your finger crosses the keyboard UI.

I want to mimic this behavior and was wondering if there was an easy way of detecting this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered a great library that handles this for you. It imitates the Messages app exactly and is easy to setup and use: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/dakeyboardcontrol

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the Messages app the logic for when the keyboard animates down does not seem to be linked to sections in the tableview. In one of my message threads it starts animating down when the top of the keyboard is in the middle of one of the message bubbles. I think the `contentOffset` of the tableview is just tracked and when it crosses a certain amount the keyboard starts to animate off the screen. You can track the `contentOffset` each time the user starts dragging the tableview by implementing the

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

and

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

methods from the UIScrollViewDelegate protocol.

Comment: Yes, please see my update to the original question. I realized that the keyboard starts to hide when your finger is dragged over the top of it, regardless of what rows/sections are being displayed.

Comment: Right. What I think they do is set the view with the UITextField as the footer view for the section. Try it, it works pretty well. All you need to do next is somehow track when the user is about to touch the top of the view with the textfield in it. You need to know where the touch is relatively to the footer view when the keyboard is being shown. You will probably have to create a custom tableview so you can override the `- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` and `- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`. It's an interesting problem :)